# How to debug Firebase networking (rewrites)? (Cloud Run call not working)

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I have setup a ML model with basic API on Cloud Run and I want to call it from my a Firebase project.

They are both in the same project and I have tested Cloud Run independently:

- Deploying a NextJS site that I am deploying to Firebase, so if I run it locally as NextJS site (`next dev`) calling my Cloud Run function over `https` it works fine:

```js
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/predict',
        destination: 'https://<cloud-run-domain>.run.app/predict',
      },
    ]
  }
```

```js
    const response = await fetch('/predict', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(CallData)
    })
```

However, when I deploy it to Firebase and setup rewrites in firebase.json. I do not get any invocations on Cloud Run side too.

```json
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "run": {
      "serviceId": "<cloud-run-service-name>",
      "region": "europe-north1"
    }
  } ]
```

The POST calls returns 404

```
{
body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:5000/predict"
}
```

This example is form a local testing using `firebase serve --only hosting` but returns the same on deployed version as well.

How do I debug Firebase rewrites and networking to figure out where the break down happens when calling the Cloud Run function?

**UPDATE:**

I was able to access the google cloud run functions using firebase rewrites functionality, but only then I put everything in central-us1, so cross server calls may not work for for this functionality or may not be implemented in all the servers

It is annoying considering that I know that all of my traffic is from EU and there may be some regulatory issues if used for production but I am just  testing things out, so for now putting everything in single server works.

Comment: As you want a way to debug what is happening and where is the issue have you tried using [Cloud Logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/web-request-logs-and-metrics)? Also sometimes the issue could be in how is written the firebase.json file, that the `rewrites` could be outside the `hosting` object and could be the reason why you are getting the 404. Could you check it?

Answer (score 0):

You first register `/api/:predict` and then call `fetch('/predict')`, which might explain the 404.
I'd assume that wildcard `"source": "**"` would also rewrite `index.html` and everything else. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrite-cloud-run-container) / [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run#direct_requests_to_container) doesn't show any `**` wildcard, because it makes no sense.

The pattern to follow is clear (notice the `source` parameter, which maps the entry-point):

```
"hosting": {
 // ...

 // Directs all requests from the page `/helloworld` to trigger and run a `helloworld` container
 "rewrites": [ {
   "source": "/helloworld",
   "run": {
     "serviceId": "helloworld",  // "service name" (from when you deployed the container image)
     "region": "us-central1"  // optional (if omitted, default is us-central1)
   }
 } ]
}
```

But one can still could map various `source` to the same `serviceId` ...
the mere question is, if http://localhost:5000/api/predict would return.

---

Not sure if one can use `functions.logger` with Cloud Run, since I use it for Cloud Functions:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
functions.logger.info(`${email} was found; UID: ${user.uid}.`);
```

But this may permit to develop suitable logging for whatever is being processed.

Also see: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-interface

Comment: Ops... the /api/:predict is from testing call I left in I did a fetch with /api/predict but later I ditched '/api/predict' for just '/predict' to make sure source needed no alterations in the docker.
And I did test  it with '/predict' instead of the '**' in the rewrite section and also with '/predict/' to test if this not trailing slash issue

Comment: I edited the question to remove the '/api/:predict' to remove the confusion for anybody else. I also validated that the updated config works locally but not then using SSL but not using rewrites to using firebase rewrites

Comment: @PovilasID did this answer helped you with your issue? if it is could you please mark it as accepted to help the community? Thanks.

Comment: @Vicky It did not help me, it suggests using firebase functions logging which does not work to see if rewrite in firebase.json was fired or not and what was sent to it, also it coppied part of documentation which does solve issue either. Thanks, for looking after the community but this answer is not helpful, so it would be misleading to mark it closed.

Comment: @PovilasID Did you ever figure out a good way to do this?

Comment: @DarkNeuron No. Well do not remember